# Is there any configurations required to show telugu unicode fonts in tcpdf?

Tags: php, unicode, fonts, tcpdf

I have to generate a PDF from php page contains html which includes unicode fonts (Telugu). Its showing perfectly when I print html code and while rendering to PDF using TCPDF, the unicode characters are distorting of letter formations.

I have copied the telugu font from google translators and added a telugu font into tcpdf lib.

```php
$message = '<h2 align="center">ధన్యవాదములు -- శుభోదయం</h2>';

$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('E:\xampp\htdocs\ncs\svdn\flowers\tcpdf\fonts\mandali-regular.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode');

$pdf->SetFont($fontname, "",30, false); 

$pdf->writeHTML($message, true, 0, true, 0);

$pdf->Output("Test.pdf", 'I');
```

The output in html is like below. And the same has to be printed in PDF too.

```
ధన్యవాదములు -- శుభోదయం
```

But in current issue, the above consonants are disjointed:

[image: picture showing disjointed consonants]

Comment: Have you [converted](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf-font) Mandali for use in TCPDF?

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF doesn't support the OpenType layout features needed for Indic scripts to work.

[mPDF supports several indic scripts - including Telugu specifically - however](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/opentype-layout-otl.html), so if you're not too far along in your project to switch, that would be my recommendation.

This code should work for instance (though I have not tested it) after installing [mPDF with composer](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html):

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
//I'm being a little lazy here and letting mPDF select the appropriate
//appropriate font.
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->baseScript = 1;  // Use values in classes/ucdn.php  1 = LATIN
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h2 style="text-align: center;">'.
     'ధన్యవాదములు -- శుభోదయం</h2>');
$mpdf->Output('test_mpdf_lang.pdf');
```