# UNICODE issues in PDF Document generated with PDFSharp

Tags: c#, .net-core, unicode, utf-8, pdfsharp

I am using Pdfshap in .Net core to generate PDF documents. Everything works fine with the English language but with other languages, Pdfsharp does not seem to be working too well. In my case have noticed some issues with the Telugu language where the characters are distorted the similar problem is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776485/is-there-any-configurations-required-to-show-telugu-unicode-fonts-in-tcpdf)

I have tried with various fonts but the issue remains the same, below the code snippet. I think there is the character encoding issue but I don't know how to fix this right. Kindly help me in the right direction.

```
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        LayoutHelper helper = new LayoutHelper(document, XUnit.FromCentimeter(1.9), XUnit.FromCentimeter(3.67));
        XPdfFontOptions opts = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode);
        XUnit left = XUnit.FromCentimeter(2.5);
        XFont font = new XFont("Mandali", "10", XFontStyle.Bold, opts);
        var vbrh = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(255, 211, 84, 0));
        helper.Gfx.DrawString("ప్రేమ", font, vbrh, 10, 10, XStringFormats.Default);
```

The first text in the image is produced by the above code which is not correct.
[image]

**UPDATE-1:**
It looks like iText7 supports ligatures through pdfCalligraph but that comes with AGPL which does not suit my project

Comment: *The current implementation of PDFsharp is limited to left-to-right languages. Languages like Arabic cannot yet be created even with Unicode fonts. Also the so called CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) support in PDF can also not be addressed with PDF sharp.* found here: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Unicode-sample.ashx not sure how out-of-date that statement is.

Comment: @rene sorry Telugu language is Left to Right which did not work

Comment: Where does that font comes from? If you show the same glyphs in a different document/program, do they show correctly?

Comment: @rene Yes while I copy-paste the distorted text from PDF to other document editors such as Notepad++ or Word it is showing correctly, I have downloaded the font from google fonts & installed on windows where the code is executed

Comment: PDFsharp 1.5x does not support ligatures. If Telugu uses ligatures then maybe this is the problem. A solution could be replacing the ligatures in your code.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow Thanks for the pointer, unfortunately, it's not easy to replace ligatures as the Telugu  language has many such & our other languages have such requirements too if this is a limitation I would rather look for another framework, could you please suggest alternatives